# import from excel error in datagridview vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

i am importing excel file in datagridview below is my code

```
'ofdImport.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls"

ofdImport.FileName = ""
If ofdImport.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

txtPath.Text = ofdImport.FileName
If txtPath.Text <> "" Then
    chkItemList.Visible = True
    dgvImportData.Visible = True
    pnlDataMsg.Visible = False
    dgvImportData.Columns.Clear()
    chkItemList.Items.Clear()
    Try
        Dim conExcel As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & txtPath.Text & " '; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        Dim excelSelect As New OleDbCommand
        Dim excelAdp As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim excelSchemaDt As DataTable
        Dim dset As New DataSet

        If conExcel.State Then conExcel.Close()
        conExcel.Open()
        excelSelect.Connection = conExcel
        excelSchemaDt = conExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        Dim sheetName As String = excelSchemaDt.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()

        excelSelect.CommandText = "select * from [" & sheetName & "] "
        excelAdp.SelectCommand = excelSelect
        excelAdp.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
        excelAdp.Fill(dset)
        dgvImportData.DataSource = dset.Tables(0)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim q(dgvImportData.Columns.Count()) As String
        For i = 0 To (dgvImportData.Columns.Count - 1)
            q(i) = (dgvImportData.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString())
        Next i
        conExcel.Close()

        i = 0
        Dim a As String = ""
        'Dim q(frmImportWizard.gridImport.Columns.Count()) As String
        For i = 0 To dgvImportData.Columns.Count - 1
            a = dgvImportData.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString()
            'CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(a)
            chkItemList.Items.Add(a)
        Next i
        chkAll.Visible = True
        chkAll.Checked = False
        lblColumnData.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
End If
```

excel file contains phone nos for eg "9874532146/8456663225" in one colms and also i have "98455566966" in same colmns 
the problem here is my code is not reading the phone numbers 
without "/" its going blank in grid 
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replaced connection string

Dim conExcel As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & txtPath.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""")
```